# Rule to save attachments on incoming emails not working on a fresh install of Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

We're migrating from one server to another and a VBA script to save attachments that was working has given up the ghost on the new server.

This is a fresh install of Outlook.

Script below:

```
Public Sub saveAttachmentAll(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String

saveFolder = "D:\www\phones"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName

    Set objAtt = Nothing

    Next

End Sub
```

I've tested the Outlook rule and Outlook is performing other actions on it but this script isn't working!

Comment: Does the folder 'D:\www\phones' exist?

Comment: Yeah, it's got other files in there already as well.  It's a fresh install of Outlook, so is there anything I'd need to do to allow the script to run in Outlook itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I had to disable macro security (which isn't the best) and restart Outlook. Fairly simple, but I was scratching my head for a while...!